# Jquery find element using data attribute of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onclicklistener, jquery-events

I have two same ids but in different divs and I am trying to create a click event

```
<div data-group = "points">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li id="first point"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>



<div data-group = "zone">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li id="first point"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created a onclick event like this

```
this._toolbox._container.on('click', "[id = 'first point']", function (ev) {
}
```

But this is listening to all the ids with 'first point'.

How can I create a click event only when 'first point' inside data-group="points" is clicked

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: The attribute *id* cannot be same

Comment: ^ Make your HTML valid first

Comment: See [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: The whole meaning of Id is to be unique identification. Which means no two elements in the same rendered dom can have same ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with the [descendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/).

```
this._toolbox._container.on('click', '[data-group="points"] [id="first point"]', function (ev) {

});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-group = "zone"] [id ="first point"]', function(ev) {
  console.log('clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-group="points">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li id="first point">1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



<div data-group="zone">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li id="first point">2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) ***which must be unique in the whole document***. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).
>
> id's value ***must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.)***. Browsers treat non-conforming IDs that contain whitespace as if the whitespace is part of the ID. In contrast to the class attribute, which allows space-separated values, elements can only have one single ID.

---

***FYI :*** The `id` should be unique in a context so always use `class` instead of `id`  for a group of elements.

*HTML :*

```
<div data-group = "points">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="first_point"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>



<div data-group = "zone">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="first_point"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Script :*

```
this._toolbox._container.on('click', '[data-group="points"] .first_point', function (ev) {

});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-group="points"] .first_point', function(ev) {
  console.log('clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-group="points">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="first_point"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



<div data-group="zone">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="first_point"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First problem is that **`id` should be unique** in whole document. Two elements shouldn't have same `id`. You should use `class` for that.You can use `[data-group=points]` before the selector.
You don't need to select `id` or `class` using attribute selector. Just use `#` for `id` and `.` for `class`

```js
$('[data-group=points] .first-point').click(function(){

  console.log("I am clicked")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-group = "points">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="first-point">one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
<div data-group = "zone">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="first-point">two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code here: The $(el).click() not work when you add a dynamic element or contents. so you can choose any one solutions.

```js
$(document).on('click','[data-group="points"] li',function(){
  console.log("you are points datagroup clicked");
});

$(document).on('click','[data-group="zone"] li',function(){
  console.log("you are points zone clicked");
});

//or 
$(document).on('click','[data-group] li',function(){
  if( $(this).parents('[data-group="points"]') ){ // check group item parent type
     console.log(" points datagroup clicked");
  }
  
  else if( $(this).parents('[data-group="zone"]') ){ // check group item parent type
     console.log("points zone clicked");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-group = "points">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="first-point">one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
<div data-group = "zone">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="first-point">two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

= = =
**Thank you**
= = =